# python flask run only one instance of method in webhook

Tags: python, flask, python-multithreading

I try to make a webhook for an update procedure in flask. The goal is to run only one instance of the run_update method simultaneously when the webhook gets called.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
def run_update():
   #... method that performs the update

t = threading.Timer(0, run_update)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not t.is_alive():
            t.start()
            return "Update started"
        else:
            return "Update is already running"
```

The problem with this approach is, that I can't start a thread twice, but unfortunately had no other idea so far how to solve that.

Thanks in advance for your ideas!:)

Comment: you will have to create new instance in every webhook - and assing to global variable `t` to check it later. OR you have to start it before webhook and inside webhook use queue or global variable to send message to thread - and thread will have use some loop to run all time.

Comment: @furas thank you! I got it working with your first approach, creating a new instance in every webhook and assigning to global variable.